# problema con gestión de colas usando array de objetos java

Tags: java

Esta es una de las partes del ejercicio con el que estoy teniendo problemas, no sé como implementar los siguientes métodos de manera correcta:

Implementar los métodos siguientes en una clase que denominaremos Cola:

a) ponerEnCola: nos permitirá introducir una persona en la cola (sólo una cada vez que elijamos esta opción). Cada persona de debe colocar a continuación de la otra.
b) salirDeCola : nos permitirá sacar una persona de la cola (la persona que sale debe ser la de la primera posición)
c) visualizarCola : nos permitirá visualizar los datos de la persona que introduzcamos por teclado

Les dejo el código de lo hecho hasta ahora:

Esta es la clase Principal:

```
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    final int TAM = 50;

    Cola gestor = new Cola();

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    Persona[] cola = new Persona[TAM];

    public Principal() {

        int opcion;
        do {
            menu();
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                int indice = 0;
                if (indice < TAM) {
                    cola = gestor.ponerEnCola(indice);
                    indice++;
                } else
                    System.out.println("No hay espacio en la cola");
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:

                gestor.visualizar();
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Fin de programa");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No has elegido ninguna de las opciones");
                break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 4);

    }

    public void menu() {
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de las siguientes opciones: ");
        System.out.println("1. Entra persona a la cola");
        System.out.println("2. Sale persona de la cola");
        System.out.println("3. Visualizar persona");
        System.out.println("4. Fin");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Principal();
    }

}
```

Esta es la clase Cola, donde se implementan los métodos:

```java
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.*;

public class Cola {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int TAM = 50;

    Persona[] cola = new Persona[TAM];

    public Persona[] ponerEnCola(int indice) {
        String dni;
        String nombre;

        System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce dni");
        dni = teclado.next();
        
        
        cola[indice]= new Persona(nombre, dni);

        return cola;
    }
    
    public void salirDeCola() {
        
    }
    
    public void visualizarCola() {
        System.out.println();
        for (Persona elemento:cola) {
            System.out.println(elemento.getNombre()+" "+elemento.getDni());
        }
    }

}
```

Y finalmente, la clase Persona:

```java
package ejercicio1;

public class Persona {

    private String dni;
    private String nombre;

    public Persona(String dni, String nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Mi problema está con la implementación de los métodos. Agradecería una ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: ¿en lugar del  arregle Persona[]  por  qué no utilizas las clases Queue, Deque con LinkedList<Persona>  o  ArrayDeque<Persona>.   Esas clases hacen todo lo que quieres sin que hagas mayor esfuerzo. Las clases se encuentran en java.util.

Comment: Porque no puedo, el ejercicio exige que lo haga de esa manera. Estoy aprendiendo la base de java y tengo que utilizar sólo lo aprendido hasta ahora. No obstante, gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Entonces, en  la  clase Cola solo deja lo relativo al manejo del arreglo. Quitale todo lo que es el Scanner porque le estarían donde  una funcionalidad  que no es de esta clase.  En vez que te pasen el indice que te pasen el objeto que quieren poner en la cola. Ah, tambien debes agregar una variable  privada a la clase Cola que  sería la que incrementas  y decrementas  para  saber  en que lugar  estás. LUego en SacarDeLaCola debes sacar el primero y  avanzar todo  el rango   desde el segundo  al primero a la posición 1. Utilizas  System.arraycopy para moverlos..

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, tras mucho pensar he dado con la solución adecuada.

```
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.*;

public class Principal {

    final int TAM = 50;

    Cola gestor = new Cola();

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    Persona[] cola = new Persona[TAM];

    int indice = 0;

    public Principal() {

        int opcion;
        do {
            menu();
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                if (indice < TAM) {
                    cola = gestor.ponerEnCola(indice);
                    indice++;
                } else
                    System.out.println("No hay espacio en la cola");
                break;
            case 2:
                gestor.salirDeCola(indice);
                System.out.println("Persona sacada de la cola");
                indice--;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (indice != 0)
                    gestor.visualizarCola(cola);
                else
                    System.out.println("No hay nadie en la cola");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Fin de programa");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No has elegido ninguna de las opciones");
                break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 4);

    }

    public void menu() {
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de las siguientes opciones: ");
        System.out.println("1. Entra persona a la cola");
        System.out.println("2. Sale persona de la cola");
        System.out.println("3. Visualizar persona");
        System.out.println("4. Fin");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Principal();
    }

}

package ejercicio1;

import java.util.*;

public class Cola {

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    final int TAM = 50;

    Persona[] cola = new Persona[TAM];

    public Persona[] ponerEnCola(int indice) {
        String dni;
        String nombre;

        System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        System.out.println("Introduce dni");
        dni = teclado.next();

        cola[indice] = new Persona(nombre, dni);

        return cola;
    }

    public void salirDeCola(int indice) {
        for(int i=0;i<indice;i++) {
            cola[i]=cola[i+1];
        }

    }

    public void visualizarCola(Persona[] cola) {
        System.out.println("Introduce posición de persona a visualizar");
        int posicion = teclado.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < cola.length; i++) {
            if (posicion == i)
                System.out.println(cola[i].getNombre() + " " + cola[i].getDni());
        }
    }

}

package ejercicio1;

public class Persona {

    private String dni;
    private String nombre;

    public Persona(String dni, String nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Finalmente, tras mucho pensar he dado con la solución adecuada.

En realidad puede mejorar:

1. ¿Qué pasa sí…?

   - Inicias tu aplicación e inmediatamente usas la opción dos (sacar persona)
     cuatro veces y después agregas una persona.
   - Cambias el tamaño máximo del *arreglo* `cola` (en la clase Cola) a uno.
2. ¿Por qué la clase Cola pide datos?
3. ¿Cuál es la diferencia de las siguientes lineas?

   - ```
     public void visualizarCola(Persona[] cola)
     ```
   - ```
     public static void visualizarCola(Persona[] cola)
     ```

En el caso uno, al no comprobar los limites se produce una excepción del tipo **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**, si solo puedes guardar un registro es más fácil ver
 que esta línea `cola[i]=cola[i+1];` va a provocar la misma excepción.
En el caso dos, la clase Cola solo debería limitarse a realizar el *«trabajo»* para el que fue
pensada, y no es que pedir datos ahí tenga algo de malo, solo no es parte de su funcionalidad.
En el caso tres, la primer línea define un método *«asociado»* a un objeto y aun así necesita
como parámetro el arreglo con el cual trabajar, cuando en realidad ya tiene acceso a el. El método
de la segunda línea no esta asociado a ningún objeto y tiene más sentido que reciba como parámetro
el arreglo con el cual trabajar.

---

El código que te presento no es muy diferente del tuyo, tú ya tienes la idea correcta
pero si quieres comparar, ¡adelante!
Persona.java

```java
package ejercicio1;

public class Persona {
    private String dni;
    private String nombre;
    
    public Persona(String dni, String nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }
    
    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }
    
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Cola.java

```java
package ejercicio1;

public class Cola {
    private int capacidad = 0;
    private int indice = 0;
    private Persona cola[];
    
    private static final int CAPACIDAD_POR_DEFECTO = 50;
    
    public Cola() {
        this(CAPACIDAD_POR_DEFECTO);
    }
    
    public Cola(int capacidad) {
        if (capacidad < 0) {
            capacidad = CAPACIDAD_POR_DEFECTO;
        }
        
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.cola = new Persona[capacidad];
    }
    
    public boolean agregar(Persona persona) {
        if (indice >= capacidad) {
            return false;
        }
        
        cola[indice++] = persona;
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public Persona remover() {
        Persona removido = null;
        
        if (indice > 0) {
            removido = cola[0];
            
            indice--;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
                cola[i] = cola[i + 1];
            }
        }
        
        return removido;
    }
    
    public Persona obtener(int indice) {
        if ((indice < 0 ) || (indice >= this.indice)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return cola[indice];
    }
    
    public int enUso() {
        return indice;
    }
    
    public int libres() {
        return capacidad - indice;
    }
}
```

Principal.java

```java
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.*;

class Principal {
    Cola gestor = new Cola();
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    protected void menu() {
        System.out.println("Selecciona una de las siguientes opciones:");
        System.out.println("1. Entra persona a la cola");
        System.out.println("2. Sale persona de la cola");
        System.out.println("3. Visualizar persona");
        System.out.println("4. Fin");
    }
    
    protected Persona nuevaPersona() {
        String dni;
        String nombre;
        Persona persona = null;
        
        System.out.print("Introduce nombre: ");
        nombre = teclado.next();
        
        System.out.print("Introduce DNI: ");
        dni = teclado.next();
        
        persona = new Persona(dni, nombre);
        
        return persona;
    }
    
    protected Persona obtenerPersona(){
        int posicion = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Introduce posición de persona a visualizar:");
        posicion = teclado.nextInt();
        
        return gestor.obtener(posicion);
    }
    
    public void iniciar() {
        Persona persona = null;
        int opcion;
        
        do {
            menu();
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    if (gestor.libres() > 0) {
                        persona = nuevaPersona();
                        
                        if (gestor.agregar(persona)) {
                            System.out.println("\n" + persona.getNombre() +
                                " agregado a la cola.\n");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("No hay espacio en la cola.\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No hay espacio en la cola.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 2:
                    persona = gestor.remover();
                    
                    if (persona != null) {
                        System.out.println("Persona sacada de la cola:" +
                            "\n Nombre: " + persona.getNombre() +
                            "\n DNI:    " + persona.getDni() + "\n");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No hay personas en la cola.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 3:
                    if (gestor.enUso() > 0) {
                        persona = obtenerPersona();
                        
                        if (persona != null) {
                            System.out.println(
                                "Nombre: " + persona.getNombre() +
                                "\nDNI   : " + persona.getDni() + "\n");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("No hay una persona en " +
                                "esta posición.\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No hay nadie en la cola.\n");
                    }
                break;
                
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Fin de programa.");
                break;
                
                default:
                    System.out.println("No has elegido ninguna de las opciones.\n");
            }
        } while (opcion != 4);
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Principal principal = new Principal();
        
        principal.iniciar();
    }
}
```